# Show that $\log(z)$ is real if z is real and positive.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Question
The problem is this:

> 1. Show that $\log(z)$ is purely imaginary (i.e. $\operatorname{Re\, Log} z$ $=$ $0$) if $|z|=1$.
> 2. Show that $\log(z)$ is real if $z$ is real and positive

---

**What I have attempted:**

For the first part to show that $\log(z)$ is purely imaginary

I let $$ z = r\operatorname{cis}(x) = re^{ix} $$

But $|z| = r = 1$ so $ z = e^{ix} $

and $$\log(z) = \log(e^{ix}) = ix $$

which is purely imaginary (Please correct me if I go wrong anywhere)

but I'm stuck proving the second part..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex logarithm is the mulita-valued function defined for $z=|z|e^{i\arg(z)}$ by

$$\log(z)=\log|z|+i(\arg(z)+2n\pi)$$

for integer $n$.  Then, if $|z|=1$, we see immediately that the logarithm is purely imaginary.

If $z=x$ is purely real and positive, then $\log(z)=\log(x)+i2n\pi$.

If we are on the principal branch of the logarithm, then $-\pi<\arg(z)\le \pi$ and $n=0$, and we find that the logarithm for $z=x>0$ is real.